# How to design table for order history when promo code is applied by user

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project in which user will order for products. Now in database I have created an `orders` table with these columns:

```
orderId, phone, address, total, subtotal, orderstatus, userid
```

In this project there will be promo code system also. I want to know that if user has applied some promo code then how can I store that data? I mean how to save data that `xyz promo code is applied by some user`. Should I add another column in order details table.But in this case I was wondering that if we will be providing users promo code only for some duration like for 3 months then just for three months should I add another column which can lead to memory waste.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can add one more field in order table  <order_date> old data is a necessary for past order which promo code used in past no memory wastage.
order_detail_promocode
---------------------- 
order table like one order
----------------------
orderId = 111
phone   = 989898
address = testing
total   = 2000
subtotal = 2020
orderstatus = 1
userid = 123
order_date = 2019-04-19  (this new column use for users promo code only for some duration like for 3 months you can check current date.)

order_detail_promocode  (which users used prome code)
userid = 123
promo_code = xyz
order_id = 111
------------------
when user new order for xyz promo code check
promo_code && user_id if available inside the sub query and get the order_date and check like last 90 days.
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can add mapping table like rather than adding new column in order table.

Table: order_promo_map
Columns: order_id 
         promo_id

But there is Join cost associated with it whenever you retrieve data.